# Mysql order a table based on two criterias

Tags: mysql

I have a problem on how to order a table based on two criterias. i have in my table games with their start and end time. so i want to show at the top games that will start soon. that's easy we can just do order by time asc. but i want when a game is ended to go to the bottom.
simple schema :

1. game1 start_at 10:00 ended at 12:00
2. game2 start_at 14:00 ended at 16:00
3. game3 start_at 20:00 ended at 22:00

so if it's 16:00 now. the result of the query display

1. game1
2. game2
3. game3

i don't want that because game1 is ended at 12:00 it's 16:00 at time now.
i want the result to be like this if its 16:00 now

1. game2
2. game3
3. game1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your columns are:

```
 game | start_time | end_time
------|------------|-----------
  g1  | 10:00      | 12:00
  g2  | 14:00      | 16:00
  g3  | 20:00      | 22:00
```

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT game FROM
(
   SELECT game, start_time, end_time, 
        (CASE end_time
              WHEN < NOW() THEN 1
              ELSE 0
         END) AS game_over
   FROM GameTimes
   ORDER BY start_time
) 
ORDER BY game_over
```

Because you don't provide enough info about your tables (ie, what format the times are actually in), I can't guarantee this will work - especially the comparison to NOW() - but it at least gets you on the right track.

Comment: the format of the time are like this 22:40 or 01:10 i mean it 24hours format